# Kafka producer api vs Apache storm's KafkaBolt

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

What are the advantages of using Apache Storm's KafkaBolt in apache storm 1.2.2 instead of using the kafka producer apis directly from the bolt in topology to publish to downstream kafka topics?

Comment: If you will open and check storm's kafkabolt code it is using Kafka Producer itselt. so It is pretty same. KafkaBolt is just a wrapper.

Comment: One "advantage" of using the bolt is that you can monitor it via the Storm UI. Disadvantages would include not making your code portable if you stopped using Storm later

Comment: Vijendra Kumar Kulhade, thanks for the reply. I have looked at the code, it is a wrapper over kafka producer and that is why my question. Why should we use it instead of using the producer itself?

Comment: cricket_007, thanks for the comment. Yes, I see the advantage of monitoring it on storm UI and it is quite useful as opposed to running the storm kafka mon script.